# How to have classes of DataTemplates?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

In my application, I would like to have DataTemplates such that I can say:

- These are the DataTemplates for use in a TreeView
- These are the DataTemplates to use when showing the summary of an object
- These are the DataTemplates to use when showing details

The only way I've seen to be able to do this is to create a DataTemplateSelector and manually return the DataTemplate (possibly by a naming convention) for the class I need.  Is there any more elegant way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're looking for, but you should just be able to define the `DataTemplate`s in a `ResourceDictionary` at the scope that most makes sense for you (Application, Window, Element or external) with an `x:Key` of the data type they're meant for and they will automatically be selected by WPF's intrinsic data template selection engine.

For example:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type myns:MyDataType}">
           <!-- your template definition here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Now wherever an instance of MyDataType is encountered within that Window WPF will automatically select that template to display its data.

Answer (score 0):

you can set DataType property of DataTemplate. At runtime template will automatically assigned to object of its Type.